# Can anyone provide me the test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
public class EmbeddedDocuSignRESTController 
{
    public Static String Loan_Prodcut = 'Loan'; 
    public Static String Lease_Prodcut = 'Lease';
    public Static String StageName_DocsExe = 'Document Creation Execution';
    public Static Attachment signTemplate;
    public class returnClass {
       @AuraEnabled public String returnURLValue;
       @AuraEnabled public String envelopId;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static EmbeddedDocuSignRESTController.returnClass callSendDocuSign(String oppId)
    {
        system.debug('oppId '+oppId);
        Boolean DocuSignSuccess = false;
        String envelopeId;
        String returnDoc;
        EmbeddedDocuSignRESTController.returnClass returnVal = new EmbeddedDocuSignRESTController.returnClass();

        try
        {   
            Opportunity oppRec = [SELECT Id, AccountId,Name,StageName, Product_Selected__r.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :oppId];
            List<Contact> contRec = [Select Id, Name, FirstName, Email, AccountId From Contact where AccountId = :oppRec.AccountId LIMIT 1];
            system.debug('Contact Records for Opportunity '+contRec);

            if(oppRec.StageName == StageName_DocsExe){
                if(oppRec.Product_Selected__r.Name == Loan_Prodcut){
                    signTemplate = [SELECT Id, Name, ParentId, Body FROM Attachment WHERE Name LIKE 'LoanContract%' AND ParentId =: oppId ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1]; 
                    system.debug('loanTemplate ****'+signTemplate);
                }else if(oppRec.Product_Selected__r.Name == Lease_Prodcut){
                    signTemplate = [SELECT Id, Name, ParentId, Body FROM Attachment WHERE Name LIKE 'LeaseContract%' AND ParentId =: oppId ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1]; 
                    system.debug('leaseTemplate ****'+signTemplate);
                }

            }
            List<String> ContactInfoList = new List<String>();
            for(Contact con:contRec)
            {
                ContactInfoList.add(con.Name);
                ContactInfoList.add(con.Email);
            }  
            system.debug('ContactInfoList '+ContactInfoList);

            String name='DocuSign Admin';
            String email=DocuSign_Credentials__c.getValues('Username').value__c;
            String accountID =DocuSign_Credentials__c.getValues('accountId').value__c;
            Transient String userName = DocuSign_Credentials__c.getValues('Username').value__c; 
            Transient String passWord = DocuSign_Credentials__c.getValues('Password').value__c;
            String integratorKey = DocuSign_Credentials__c.getValues('IntegratorKey').value__c;
            String templateID = DocuSign_Credentials__c.getValues('TemplateID').value__c;
            String BrandCode = DocuSign_Credentials__c.getValues('BrandCode').value__c;
            String docusignURL = DocuSign_Credentials__c.getValues('endPointURL').value__c;

            String endPoint = docusignURL +accountID+ '/envelopes';
            DocuSignUtilRESTCall.brandId = BrandCode; 
            DocuSignUtilRESTCall.ContactInfoList=ContactInfoList;
            if(signTemplate != null){
              DocuSignUtilRESTCall.docuSignTemplate = signTemplate;  
            }
            //DocuSignUtilRESTCall.docuSignTemplate = signTemplate; 
            DocuSignUtilRESTCall.docuSigntemplateId = templateID;
            DocuSignUtilRESTCall.oppId = oppId; 

            String jsonPayload = DocuSignUtilRESTCall.getJsonPayload(); 
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(endPoint);  
            req.setMethod('POST');  
            req.setTimeout(50000);
            String authorizationHeader = '<DocuSignCredentials><Username>' + userName + '</Username><Password>' + Password + 

                '</Password><IntegratorKey>' + integratorKey + '</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>';
            System.debug('Authorization:' + authorizationHeader);
            req.setHeader('X-DocuSign-Authentication', authorizationHeader);
            req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
            req.setHeader('Content-Length', '162100');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            req.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'form-data');
            req.setBody(jsonPayload);               
            HttpResponse res;
            Http http = new Http();
            try {
                res = http.send(req);
                system.debug('DocuSign Response' + res.getBody() +'*****'+res.getStatus()); 
                 if(res.getStatus()=='Created'){
                    System.debug('DocuSign Created ' + res.getBody());
                    DocuSignResponse DocuRes= DocuSignResponse.parse(res.getBody());
                    system.debug(DocuRes.envelopeId);
                     envelopeId = DocuRes.envelopeId;
                     //DocuSignSuccess=true;

                 }else {  
                    System.debug('DocuSign Response Failed' + res.getBody());
                    DocuSignSuccess = false;
                    //saveSuccess=true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                DocuSignSuccess = false; 
                System.debug('DocuSign Exception' + res.getBody());
            }

            String documentJsonPayload = DocuSignUtilRESTCall.getdocumentJsonPayload();

            String documentEndPoint = docusignURL +accountID+ '/envelopes/'+envelopeId+'/views/recipient';
            system.debug('documentEndPoint '+documentEndPoint);
            HttpRequest documentReq = new HttpRequest();
            documentReq.setEndpoint(documentEndPoint);  
            documentReq.setMethod('POST');  
            documentReq.setTimeout(50000);
            String documentAuthorizationHeader = '<DocuSignCredentials><Username>' + userName + '</Username><Password>' + Password + 

                '</Password><IntegratorKey>' + integratorKey + '</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>';
            System.debug('Authorization:' + documentAuthorizationHeader);
            documentReq.setHeader('X-DocuSign-Authentication', documentAuthorizationHeader);
            documentReq.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
            documentReq.setHeader('Content-Length', '162100');
            documentReq.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            documentReq.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'form-data');
            system.debug('documentReq '+documentReq);
            documentReq.setBody(documentJsonPayload);               
            HttpResponse documentRes;
            Http documenthttp = new Http();
            try {
                system.debug('in document fetch try block');
                documentRes = documenthttp.send(documentReq);
                system.debug('Document fetch DocuSign Response' + documentRes.getBody() +'*****'+documentRes.getStatus()); 
                documentDocuSignResponse parsedDocResponse= documentDocuSignResponse.parse(documentRes.getBody());
                system.debug(parsedDocResponse.url); 
                returnDoc = parsedDocResponse.url;
                system.debug('returnDoc url is '+returnDoc);
                DocuSignSuccess=true;
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.debug('Document fetch  DocuSign Exception' + documentRes.getBody());
                DocuSignSuccess=false;
            }



        }catch(Exception e){
            DocuSignSuccess=false;
            system.debug('Exception in Docusign'+e.getMessage()+e.getLineNumber()); 
        }
        if(DocuSignSuccess)
        {
            system.debug('DocuSignSuccess'+DocuSignSuccess);

            returnVal.returnURLValue = returnDoc;
            returnVal.envelopId = envelopeId;
        //    callAttachDocuSignStatus(envelopeId);
        }

       // return returnDoc;
        return returnVal;
    }

    //Method used to check the status of DocuSign Envelop
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean checkDocuSignSuccess(String envelopId)
    {
        Boolean isSuccess;
        dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c envelopRec = [Select id, dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope_ID__c, dsfs__Envelope_Status__c  from dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c where dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope_ID__c=:envelopId LIMIT 1];
        if(envelopRec.dsfs__Envelope_Status__c=='Completed')
        {
            isSuccess=true;
        }
        else
        {
            isSuccess=false;
        }
        return isSuccess;
    }
}
```

TestClass:

```
@isTest
public class EmbeddedDocuSignRESTControllerTest {
    static testmethod void test() {
        Account testAcct = new Account (Name = 'My Test Account');
        insert testAcct;
        Contact con = new Contact(accountid=testAcct.id,lastname='test con',email='xyz@gmail.com');
        insert con;
        Contact con2 = new Contact(accountid=testAcct.id,lastname='test con2',email='yzx@gmail.com');
        insert con2;
        List<String> cons = new List<String>() ;
        cons.add(con.email);
        cons.add(con2.email);
        Opportunity  oppt= new Opportunity(Name ='New mAWS Deal',
                                           AccountID = testAcct.ID,
                                           StageName = 'Document Creation Execution',
                                           Amount = 3000,
                                           CloseDate = System.today());

        insert oppt;
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.ParentId = testAcct.Id;
        attachment.Name = 'LoanContract';
        Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
        attachment.Body = bodyBlob;
        insert attachment;
        Product2 prod = TestDataBuilderClass.getLoanProduct();
        Test.startTest();
        EmbeddedDocuSignRESTController.callSendDocuSign(oppt.Id);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Please help me in writing the above test class.I have started writing it but i am not able to succeed.Could anyone help me in writing the code for Custom Settings part of the code.

Comment: Hi @mahesh! What is your issue? What did you already try and what issue you are facing?

Comment: I am facing the issue at signTemplate = [SELECT Id, Name, ParentId, Body FROM Attachment WHERE Name LIKE 'LoanContract%' AND ParentId =: oppId ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];  How do i cover that in the code coverage

Comment: Are you adding any attachment? If no, you need to add and make sure that the query requirements will be OK

Comment: Yes i am adding attachment as below:Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.ParentId = testAcct.Id;
        attachment.Name = 'LoanContract';
        Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
        attachment.Body = bodyBlob;
        insert attachment; Even then i am unable to cover it

Comment: I suggest to edit your question and add info there....

Answer (score 3):

The test data you are creating does not match your class's expectations. You need to pass two `if` checks to get to the line of code,

```
signTemplate = [SELECT Id, Name, ParentId, Body FROM Attachment WHERE Name LIKE 'LoanContract%' AND ParentId =: oppId ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
```

which you note in a comment that you are unable to cover. Those `if` checks are

```
        if(oppRec.StageName == StageName_DocsExe){
            if(oppRec.Product_Selected__r.Name == Loan_Prodcut){
```

It appears that your test data does pass the first `if`, but cannot pass the second because you do not populate the `Product_Selected__c` lookup with a related record matching the second `if`. It looks like you try to load a Product with

```
    Product2 prod = TestDataBuilderClass.getLoanProduct();
```

but you never connect it to your Opportunity. Make that change, and the line in question should be covered.

Note that since you have branching logic in your class, you will need to write more than one unit test, supplying different test data, to fully cover and validate all of your code paths. Additionally, you **must** write assertions to demonstrate that the behavior of your code is correct, or this is nothing but a smoke test. SFSE has links to many valuable unit testing resources under the [`canonical-qa`](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-qa) tag.